# Windows: how to pass all traffic to a specific port via an HTTP proxy?

Tags: proxy, port

Short version of the need:

1. Pass all traffic of a *specific* port (TCP) via a proxy
2. It should be an HTTP proxy with port 8000

*Description*

I have an application that needs to reach an external IP with a specific port (TCP). But the standard corporate network blocks outbound traffic to this port.

I can, however, access that port when working with the corporate HTTP proxy that works on port 8000.

Alas, my application does not have any proxy settings, and IE's proxy settings are irrelevant.

Port forwarding and tunneling won't do me any good (already tried netsh anyway), since I need not only to reach the proxy, but I need it to actually function as a proxy.

Can anyone recommend on a method / software that will allow me to pass all traffic to port X via a proxy?

It has to be the traffic of a specific port, since there is a web server installed on that machine and I don't want to temper with it.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find solution to your issue. I am struggling with same issue

Comment: Sorry, @AhmedRana, but I didn't find a solution eventually. That was 6 years ago, but I doubt much have changed in the way Windows works.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't route by port. The real answer is send the traffic to a firewall or layer 3 device that can route by port.

But,

If you know the ip address of the destination you could force that traffic to the proxy if the proxy address is on the same subnet. If it's not on the same subnet your computer will try to send the traffic to that as a gateway but it won't be avaiable (it won't be routed). But, it's so simple it's worth a try.

Example....
Computer 192.168.1.10, 255.255.255.0
Proxy 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
Destination IP. 68.68.68.68

route add -p  'destination ip' 'destination subnet range' 'where to send traffic, normally the next hop gateway'

Using example addresses (replace the two addreses with yours but keep 255.255.255.255) 
Open Command prompt as administrator, Type `route add -p 68.68.68.68 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.254`

Using 255.255.255.255 forces it to only route one address.

-p will make the route stay after a reboot.

If it doesn't work you can remove the route simply route delete 'destination ip'

```
Route delete 68.68.68.68
```

Comment: thank you. This could be a good option if I was allowed to tamper with any other port than the one I need for the specific application, and I am not...

It has to be a specific port that will go through the proxy.

Comment: I figured it was a little far off but since windows doesn't offer port routing it might be an option.